# Central Administration pointing to wrong port

Tags: administration, wss-3.0

When I log into WSS 3.0 Central Administration it is pointing to an old tcp port which was used for testing.  How do I configure this to open to my main site?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what you mean. Central Admin runs on a different port than your main Sharepoint site.

Comment: When I log into central admin it looks to http://bmashpnt:26272/default.aspx which isn't the proper address.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, based on data available to me, is that you changed admin port but did not update it properly in SharePoint. Check:

```
stsadm -o setadminport
```

command for more details. [TechNet documentation...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262249%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: When I attempt the stsadm -o setadminport I get the response "The term stsadm is not a recongized cmdlet, etc.  From other reading I see that a profile.ps1 file needs to be added.  Is this just a notepad file?  I added a profile.ps1.txt file but it stilldoesn't work.

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Just reprovision it to the new port.  Run STSADM -o adminvs -provision -port xxxx